# How come i can import org.jfree.ui, but not org.jfree.chart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm trying to create a new JFreeChart, i have both JCommon (1.0.22) and JFreeChart (1.0.17-demo) in my Build Path for the project;

However, when i try to create code, in this case;

```
        CategoryDataset dataset = createDataset();
    JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
    ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart, false);
    chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 270));
    setContentPane(chartPanel);
```

I get an Error at "JFreeChart" with no Import option available.

I'm using the guide here:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartBarChartDemo1.htm

To try and create a Chart (Just to check imports right now)
But i can import org.jfree.(anything) like org.jfree.ui

BUT i cannot import org.jfree.chart

As it says it doesn't exist in my libraries. Any ideas?

Comment: You say you have "1.0.17-demo" in your build path - you mean you only have the demo jar in your classpath and not the library jar? You should have "jfreechart-1.0.17.jar" in your classpath as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jfreechart-1.0.17-demo.jar` is the JAR file that contains demo examples, not the actual library.

Look in the `lib` folder and use `jfreechart-1.0.17.jar`.

Answer (score 1):

two library is needed:

- **jcommon-1.0.23.jar**
- **jfreechart-1.0.19.jar**

(the demo jar is not library. it's a great sample of outputs you can have.)